# Which website teach how to create plugin programming?

Tags: joomla

Which website teach how to create joomla plugin programming or ebook or video?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like these sites:

http://www.learnwebdesignonline.com/tutorials/joomla/create-simple-plugin
http://www.dcpagesapps.com/developer-resources/joomla/10-joomla-plugin-tutorial

If you have more specific questions, I can give you a more specific answer but these tutorials will help you start down the plug-in development road.

Answer (score 0):

start by reading joomla doc

http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin

http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla_1.5

http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_content_plugin